# Wrong allignment when drawing a JTextPane into a BufferedImage

Tags: java, jtextpane, text-alignment

I am trying to draw some styled text into a buffered image. I use a JTextPane which is not part of any view hierarchy. I set the document properties with the desired alignment but the results are not correctly aligned. Even worse, I would get different results for different font size or sometimes even different results when running the same test again.

The following image shows the results. The paragraphs should be be, top to bottom, aligned left, center, right, full. The red frame is the JTextPane border. See for your self.

Because I am a new stackoverflow user, it did not allow me to post an image. You can see the image at http://www.sendtoprint.net/preview/textfile.jpg

This was done on Java 1.7 but did also happen in 1.6. The code:

```
public void createBufferedImage ()
    {
    try
        {
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage (1000, 1200, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D gg = bi.createGraphics ();

        gg.setRenderingHint (RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        gg.setRenderingHint (RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS, RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);

        gg.setBackground (Color.white);
        gg.fillRect (0, 0, bi.getWidth (), bi.getHeight ());

        gg.scale (3.0f, 3.0f);
        gg.translate (16, 16);

        String text = "The residents of Colorado and Washington state have voted to legalize "
                + "the recreational use of marijuana, and all hell is about to break "
                + "loose -- at least ideologically. The problem is that pot is still very much "
                + "illegal under federal law, and the Obama administration must decide whether "
                + "to enforce federal law in a state that has rejected the substance of that law."
                + "\n\n";


        DefaultStyledDocument doc = new DefaultStyledDocument ();

        MutableAttributeSet attr = new SimpleAttributeSet ();
        StyleConstants.setFontFamily (attr, "Arial");
        StyleConstants.setFontSize (attr, 9);
        StyleConstants.setForeground (attr, Color.black);

        MutableAttributeSet parAttr = new SimpleAttributeSet ();

        doc.insertString (0, text, attr);

        StyleConstants.setAlignment (parAttr, StyleConstants.ALIGN_LEFT);
        doc.setParagraphAttributes (0, doc.getLength (), parAttr, false);

        doc.insertString (doc.getLength (), text, attr);

        StyleConstants.setAlignment (parAttr, StyleConstants.ALIGN_CENTER);
        doc.setParagraphAttributes (doc.getLength () - text.length (), text.length (), parAttr, false);

        doc.insertString (doc.getLength (), text, attr);

        StyleConstants.setAlignment (parAttr, StyleConstants.ALIGN_RIGHT);
        doc.setParagraphAttributes (doc.getLength () - text.length (), text.length (), parAttr, false);

        doc.insertString (doc.getLength (), text, attr);

        StyleConstants.setAlignment (parAttr, StyleConstants.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED);
        doc.setParagraphAttributes (doc.getLength () - text.length (), text.length (), parAttr, false);

        JTextPane tc = new JTextPane ();
        tc.setBorder (BorderFactory.createLineBorder (Color.red, 1));
        tc.setDocument (doc);
        tc.setBackground (Color.white);
        tc.setLocation (0, 0);
        tc.setSize (new Dimension (300, 370));
        tc.paint (gg);

        System.out.println ("Writing file: " + new Date ().toString ());

        File file = new File ("C:\\Users\\Yishai\\Desktop\\text\\file.jpg");
        ImageIO.write (bi, "jpg", file);
        }
    catch (Exception e)
        {
        System.out.println (e.getMessage ());
        }
    }
```

Any ideas what can I do differently? is there a JTextPane setting? A text cache? anything?

Thanks.